# Extending __all__. How can I take module __all__ list?

Tags: python, python-module

I want to do something like this?

```
# __init__.py
import a_module

__all__ = [
    'a_module',
]

__all__.extend(a_module.__all__)  # it doesn't work
# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__all__'
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Any errors?

Comment: @alecxe I added some description

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I don't see why you just don't:

```
from a_module import *
```

...if all you want to do is re-publish everything `a_module` publishes... This is even a case where the PEP8 "sanctions" the use of the star import, which it normally discourages.

...now if the above solution is not what works for you, here's more or less a hand-written equivalent:

`dir()` should give you the list of attributes in an object (incl. a module):

```
__all__.extend(dir(a_module))
```

If you'd like to filter out the stuff starting with `__` and `_`, just:

```
__all__.extend(x for x in dir(a_module) if not x.startswith('_'))
```

This should work regardless of whether the module has declared `__all__` or not.

And, to fully mimic Python's default behavior of considering all non-underscore-prefixed things in a module as public, unless `__all__` is declared:

```
__all__.extend((x for x in dir(a_module) if not x.startswith('_'))
               if not hasattr(a_module, '__all__')
               else a_module.__all__)
```

Comment: Suit yourself—I prefer the ternary if: in this case, I find it just as readable, with the advantage that it doesn't duplicate the `__all__.extend(...)` part of the logic, so it's completely DRY. But I'm also a bit more used to functional programming style where `if-else` (just as every other part of the language) is an expression and thus anything can be nested.

Comment: I think it will better to write block if ... else statement instead of inline. Inline if's sometimes look like magic

Comment: Whether something looks magic, normal or even nice, is really a matter of what you're used to, what's your background, and your general tendency to like one thing/style over another. However, I'd be more interested to know why `from a_module import *` doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: b-module---a_module---a_module_internal.
I want to have ability to import part of a_module internals from b_module. I should look like interface(this is just a word)

Comment: "ability to import (part of) `a_module` internals from `b_module`" ...but isn't that exactly what `from a_module import *` does? —i.e. make stuff in `a_module` importable from `b_module`...